# How to store affiliate ID correctly to browser

Tags: php, caching, affiliate

1. I want to create a simple affiliate code.
2. Currently I use PHP session to keep the affiliate ID. `http://domain.com/aff.php?id=123`

   `$_SESSION['referral'] = intval($_GET['id']);`

The problem now. Example user logged to affiliate area then logout, the `$_SESSION['referral']` will unset & destroyed by `session_unset() session_destroy()` on `logout.php`

So now the `affiliate ID` no more on the page. So we need to retype the URL to get the ID sticked on the whole web pages.

**Question**

How to make the `affiliate id` `id=123` will be on the browser although session already destroyed. Unless user clear the browser cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the affiliate id into a cookie, so it is still available after the session expires.

```
setcookie("affiliate", intval($_GET['id']);
```

see [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)